# Execute Command within another directory

Tags: unix

I am trying to execute a command from a different directory but I keep getting a "No such file or directory" response. I have been stuck for about 6 hours now and cannot figure it out. I am very new so please take it easy.

I created a directory (Learning) with a subdirectory (fileAsst), and two subdirectories (Earth, Galaxy) within "fileAsst." I am trying to execute a separate file to check to see if I have built the desired directory correctly.

I type in ~unix/bin/fileAsst-1 to try and execute to my directory. But it just is not working. Please help.

```
Learning/fileAsst/Earth/zaphod.txt
Learning/fileAsst/Galaxy/trillian.txt

~unix/bin/fileAsst-1 (what I'm trying to execute to check my Learning directory)
```

Comment: What does "just not working" mean?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's almost always true that the easy thing is worst thing you can do. Be gentle? You bet. But to get good answers more quickly, you have to know how the community works.

Comment: Part of a good question for this apparent context (getting an error from a shell script), would be to paste into your question a heading "This is what I execute and what I get in response" followed by you pasting what your shell windows says. One way to do that correctly is to copy the contents of the window that you want to paste into your question. Then you edit a file and paste the content into that window. Then add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line. Then copy the editor's lines and paste them into your question. Then we can all see what you typed and what you got in response.

Comment: If I'm correct and you're getting an error from shell script ~unix/bin/fileAsst-1, then you might figure out your problem by adding `set -x` to your shell script before executing it again. In summary, though, if I'm on the right track, then what you need to search for, over the whole web, is "how to debug shell scripts".

Comment: The notation `~unix/bin/…` means the home directory of a user called `unix` (and the `bin` sub-directory of that home directory).  Did you perhaps mean `~/unix/bin/…`, meaning your home directory (as specified via the `$HOME` environment variable), and the `unix/bin` sub-directory of your home directory?  It isn't clear from your description, yet, where the `fileAsst-1` script is stored (witness this comment), or where the `Learning` directory is (but it seems like that it is `~/Learning`).

Answer (score 0):

My guess, based upon your usage of the phrase "execute to my directory", you need to read something like [this](https://swcarpentry.github.io/shell-novice/02-filedir/).

I cannot be sure but it appears as though you want to change your current directory to some other directory using the `cd` command. Having set your current working directory appropriately you wish to execute some command.

But a guess is only a guess and it's somewhat dangerous to give an answer when unfamiliar nouns and verbs are used in the question.